# How to show python script status in gui tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am totally new to tkinter and trying to figure out the way to show the python script status to gui window.
Below is my simple basic python program

```
def myFunc():
   print("Hello world")   #print 

if __name__ == "__main__" :
   myFunc()    #calling the function
```

if I run this python file on cmd it will print the message, similarly
How can I show print messages to gui tkinter window??

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("Title here")

lbl = Label(window, text="Hello World"))

lbl.pack()

window.mainloop()
```